# Vue.js component only updating after browser page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

So I am still quite new to Vue.js or any reactive framework for that matter.

I have a component that I need to have update whenever a change is made. The idea is that it is taking a balance from a specific login.

```
<li :key="balance">Balance {{ balance }}</li>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      games: [],
      balance: '101',
      error: ''
    }
}
```

```
async created() {
    try{
      this.balance = await WalletService.getBalance();
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  }
```

From my own debugging, it looks like the created() function is not being called after my router.push() when the user logs in. How can I ensure that created() is called after router.push

Comment: try using `mounted()` instead of `created()`?

Comment: So when I switch from created() to mounted() I still have the same issue, but I now get an error in the console "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `async` keyword from `created()`.

Although lifecycle methods can perform asynchronous code, the lifecycle itself is synchronous.